# Wrapbootstrap integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Good Afternoon All,

I'm having trouble integrating this template into my rails application. I've changes all the images and loaded all the files into their relevant areas. However they still have the subdirectories.

Does anyone know of a guide I can walk through which might explain how you do this, especially to include the revolution-slider which has a whole subdirectory of CSS and images.

Template being used:

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/pixma-responsive-multipurpose-template-WB0B348C6

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggesting that you are on Rails > 3 with asset-pipeline on, the process of integration should be trivial like in [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), look for 2.2.2 - using index files):

1. Copy your directories under your `app/assets/javascripts|stylesheets` , for example : `app/assets/stylesheets/revolution-slider`
2. Create a new manifest file named `index.css` (for stylesheets assets) and `index.js` (for js assets) . It should be inside the library directory and should contain regular directives for including assets , usually `*= require_tree .` for styles and `//= require_tree .` for `js`.
3. Finally, include your library in your main manifest file `application.css|js` like this:

   ```
   //=require revolution-slider
   ```

for javascript library

```
    *= require revolution-slider
```

for `css` library.