# WrapBootstrap template doesn't work

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just purchased a `wrap bootstrap` template and tried to use it on a ruby on rails app.  I pasted all its images files under my local `/app/assets/images` folder, js files under `/app/assets/javascripts`  , html files under `/app/views` and all css files under `/app/assets/stylesheets`.

When I just clicked the html file it's working correctly. But when I tried to run localhost, it just showed the basic html files without any pictures or font styles.

Comment: If you can please be more specific about the issues you are experiencing, it's more likely that you'll get a good quality answer. What do `application.html.erb` and `gemfile` look like? Also, try the suggestions provided in these answers: [_Implementing bootstrap theme from wrapbootstrap_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762660/implementing-bootstrap-theme-from-wrapbootstrap) and [_Wrapbootstrap integration_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813507/wrapbootstrap-integration).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I ran into this Exact problem myself recently. The way I solved this was to:

Open the downloaded WrapBootstrap template contents (example mine had various pages but two main folders Documentation and HTML). Inside of the HTML folder there should be a sub folder named **assets**. Copy and paster this entire folder into you public folder.

The next step which had me beating my head into the table was when you use a page of the HTML in the template the CSS and JS is all referenced in a similiar way example:

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/layer-slider.js"></script>
```

But when you place it into your **application.html.erb** file you need to make sure you place a leading **/** (slash) in front of assets like so:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/plugins/layer-slider.js"></script>
```

So that now the assets are being referenced from an absolute path rather than a relative one.